# Cloud Function for Firebase timeout after 60 seconds while running a bunch of Firebase queries

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am using Firebase for a group collaboration app (like Whatsapp) and I am using a Cloud Function to figure out which of the phone contacts are also using my app (again similar to Whatsapp). The Cloud Function ran fine till I started to see the following log in the Functions Log for some invocations.

`Function execution took 60023 ms, finished with status: 'timeout'`

I did some debugging and found that for this particular user, he has a lot of contacts on his phone's contacts book and so obviously the work required to figure out which of those contacts are using the app also increased to a point that it took more than 60 secs. Below is the code for the Cloud Function

```
      // contactsData is an array of contacts on the user's phone
      // Each contact can contain one more phone numbers which are
      // present in the phoneNumbers array. So, essentially, we need
      // to query over all the phone numbers in the user's contact book
      contactsData.forEach((contact) => {
        contact.phoneNumbers.forEach((phoneNumber) => {
          // Find if user with this phoneNumber is using the app
          // Check against mobileNumber and mobileNumberWithCC
          promises.push(ref.child('users').orderByChild("mobileNumber").
            equalTo(phoneNumber.number).once("value").then(usersSnapshot => {
              // usersSnapshot should contain just one entry assuming
              // that the phoneNumber will be unique to the user
              if(!usersSnapshot.exists()) {
                return null
              }
              var user = null
              usersSnapshot.forEach(userSnapshot => {
                user = userSnapshot.val()
              })
              return {
                name: contact.name,
                mobileNumber: phoneNumber.number,
                id: user.id
              }
            }))
          promises.push(ref.child('users').orderByChild("mobileNumberWithCC").
            equalTo(phoneNumber.number).once("value").then(usersSnapshot => {
              // usersSnapshot should contain just one entry assuming
              // that the phoneNumber will be unique to the user
              if(!usersSnapshot.exists()) {
                return null
              }
              var user = null
              usersSnapshot.forEach(userSnapshot => {
                user = userSnapshot.val()
              })
              return {
                name: contact.name,
                mobileNumber: phoneNumber.number,
                id: user.id
              }
            }))
        });
      });
      return Promise.all(promises)
    }).then(allContacts => {
      // allContacts is an array of nulls and contacts using the app
      // Get rid of null and any duplicate entries in the returned array
      currentContacts = arrayCompact(allContacts)

      // Create contactsObj which will the user's contacts that are using the app
      currentContacts.forEach(contact => {
        contactsObj[contact.id] = contact
      })
      // Return the currently present contacts
      return ref.child('userInfos').child(uid).child('contacts').once('value')
    }).then((contactsSnapshot) => {
      if(contactsSnapshot.exists()) {
        contactsSnapshot.forEach((contactSnapshot) => {
          previousContacts.push(contactSnapshot.val())
        })
      }
      // Update the contacts on firease asap after reading the previous contacts
      ref.child('userInfos').child(uid).child('contacts').set(contactsObj)

      // Figure out the new, deleted and renamed contacts
      newContacts = arrayDifferenceWith(currentContacts, previousContacts, 
        (obj1, obj2) => (obj1.id === obj2.id))
      deletedContacts = arrayDifferenceWith(previousContacts, currentContacts,
        (obj1, obj2) => (obj1.id === obj2.id))
      renamedContacts = arrayIntersectionWith(currentContacts, previousContacts,
        (obj1, obj2) => (obj1.id === obj2.id && obj1.name !== obj2.name))
      // Create the deletedContactsObj to store on firebase
      deletedContacts.forEach((deletedContact) => {
        deletedContactsObj[deletedContact.id] = deletedContact
      })
      // Get the deleted contacts
      return ref.child('userInfos').child(uid).child('deletedContacts').once('value')
    }).then((deletedContactsSnapshot) => {
      if(deletedContactsSnapshot.exists()) {
        deletedContactsSnapshot.forEach((deletedContactSnapshot) => {
          previouslyDeletedContacts.push(deletedContactSnapshot.val())
        })
      }
      // Contacts that were previously deleted but now added again
      restoredContacts = arrayIntersectionWith(newContacts, previouslyDeletedContacts,
        (obj1, obj2) => (obj1.id === obj2.id))
      // Removed the restored contacts from the deletedContacts
      restoredContacts.forEach((restoredContact) => {
        deletedContactsObj[restoredContact.id] = null
      })
      // Update groups using any of the deleted, new or renamed contacts
      return ContactsHelper.processContactsData(uid, deletedContacts, newContacts, renamedContacts)
    }).then(() => {
      // Set after retrieving the previously deletedContacts
      return ref.child('userInfos').child(uid).child('deletedContacts').update(deletedContactsObj)
    })
```

Below is some sample data

```
// This is a sample contactsData
[
  {
    "phoneNumbers": [
      {
        "number": "12324312321",
        "label": "home"
      },
      {
        "number": "2322412132",
        "label": "work"
      }
    ],
    "givenName": "blah5",
    "familyName": "",
    "middleName": ""
  },
  {
    "phoneNumbers": [
      {
        "number": "1231221221",
        "label": "mobile"
      }
    ],
    "givenName": "blah3",
    "familyName": "blah4",
    "middleName": ""
  },
  {
    "phoneNumbers": [
      {
        "number": "1234567890",
        "label": "mobile"
      }
    ],
    "givenName": "blah1",
    "familyName": "blah2",
    "middleName": ""
  }
]



// This is how users are stored on Firebase. This could a lot of users
  "users": {
    "id1" : {
      "countryCode" : "91",
      "id" : "id1",
      "mobileNumber" : "1231211232",
      "mobileNumberWithCC" : "911231211232",
      "name" : "Varun"
    },
    "id2" : {
      "countryCode" : "1",
      "id" : "id2",
      "mobileNumber" : "2342112133",
      "mobileNumberWithCC" : "12342112133",
      "name" : "Ashish"
    },
    "id3" : {
      "countryCode" : "1",
      "id" : "id3",
      "mobileNumber" : "123213421",
      "mobileNumberWithCC" : "1123213421",
      "name" : "Pradeep Singh"
    }
  }
```

In this particular case, the `contactsData` contained `1046` entries and for some of those entries, there were two `phoneNumbers`. So, let's assume there were a total of `1500` phone numbers that I need to check. I am creating queries to compare against the `mobileNumber` and `mobileNumberWithCC` for the users in the database. So, there are a total of `3000` queries that the function will make before the promise finishes and I am guessing it is taking more than 60 seconds to finish up all those queries and hence the Cloud Function timed out.

My few questions are:

1. Is it expected for all those queries to take more than 60 secs? I was expecting it to finish much faster given that it is running within the Firebase infrastructure.
2. Is there a way to increase the timeout limit for a function? I am currently on Blaze plan.

I will also appreciate any alternate implementation suggestions for the above function in order alleviate the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused.  You're querying for all this data, but you're not doing anything with it.  All I see is that you're returning an object from then().  Normally you're supposed to return another promise from then() *or* actually make use of it in a chained then().

Comment: @DougStevenson I skipped that piece of code to keep it simple. Basically, above code will return me an array of contacts which are using my app. I upload these contacts to Firebase which is read by the app to populate the list of contacts using the app. I also perform other things such as figuring out any deleted, restored and renamed contacts since the last sync and then update groups that use such contacts in the app. I have updated the code a little bit to reflect that. Based on my logging, the function times out before `Promise.all` call finished.

Comment: OK, querying for thousands of items seems excessive in any case, espcially if you're only going to use a single item.  You should find a way to structure your data and query to return only the few items you need at the beginning.

Comment: @DougStevenson I am not sure why you think I am going to use a single item. I am interested in the result of all of those thousand queries. For eg. let's say I have 100,000 users using my app which I store in the `users` branch of the database and I store very minimal information per user. Now a user starts the app and he has 1000 contacts in this contact book and I need to figure out which of those 1000 contacts are using the app. So, I will have to at least run 1000 queries. If all of those 1000 contacts are using the app, I will be using the result of all those queries.

Comment: In this code: `usersSnapshot.forEach(userSnapshot => { user = userSnapshot.val() })` you are iterating everything in usersSnapshot, but only remembering a single user out of that collection, whatever came last.  Maybe it would help if you added some comments about what you're trying to accomplish at each stage, along with a sample of some data, because this is difficult to imagine what all you have structured here.

Comment: @DougStevenson I expect the `usersSnapshot` to have just one user. I am looping over the `contactsData` which is an array of phone contacts. Each contact can have multiple phone numbers but usually just one. So, loop over each phone number in the contact. And then I run `ref.child('users').orderByChild("mobileNumber").equalTo(phoneNumber.number).once("value")` query to check if the user with that phone number is using the app which should be just one user. Since it would be returned as a `DataSnapshot` and I need the actual user record, I do the `forEach` thing. 1/2

Comment: @DougStevenson I can also do usersSnapshot.val() here and get the first result if that will make the query faster. I have added some more comments to the code. I will add some sample data also. 2/2

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you cannot avoid querying so much data, you can change the timeout of a function in the [Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) for your project using the Functions product on the left.  Currently, you will have to reset the timeout with each new deploy.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This will solve my problem for the time being. I will really look forward to any comments that you may have about how I could structure and query my data for this workflow. My workflow is pretty simple. I have a list of users using my app in Firebase. Each user contains a mobileNumber. For a given array of mobileNumbers, I want to find out which of those mobileNumbers are using the app. Thanks again for your comments and response. I can now release a new version of my app using cloud functions instead of firebase-queue worker :)

Comment: So, it turned out to be a combination of timeout and memory allocated to the function. Initially, I just changed the time to 120 seconds but it still timed out. Then, I increased the memory allocated from 256 MB to 512 MB and then function finished in 64 seconds. Not sure if I should increase the allocated memory further and how would it affect the costing and time it takes to finish the function, but I will run some tests. Thanks!

Comment: You are definitely paying for a combination of time and memory when you're on the Blaze plan, according to the pricing page.

Comment: Yea, that's what I was thinking that if I just increase the memory allocated for the function to say 1 GB, then it would also affect the pricing for the invocations of the same function that finish in less than 100 ms which is 95% of the invocations. I don't think the increased memory would affect the time taken to finish those invocations proportionately. I will run some tests with respect to that and try to come up with the right combination.

Answer (score 13):

## The Problem

Your performance problem you experience comes from the query  `ref.child('users').orderByChild("mobileNumber").equalTo(phon‌​eNumber.number).once‌​("value")` which you are calling from within a `forEach()` inside another `forEach()`.

To break down this query, you are essentially asking the database to **iterate** through the children of `/users`, compare the key `mobileNumber` to `phon‌​eNumber.number` and if they match, return a value. However, not only are you calling this for both `mobileNumber` and `mobileNumberWithCC`, you are calling this on **every iteration** of `forEach()`. So this means that you are looking over `X` amount of users for `Y` amount of phone numbers, for `Z` amount of contacts, therefore performing up to `X*Y*Z` internal database operations. This is obviously taxing and hence why your query takes over 60 seconds to process.

## Potential Fix

I would recommend implementing an index on your database, called `/phoneNumbers`. Each key in `/phoneNumbers` is to be named `n###########` or `c###########` and contains an "array" of user IDs associated with that phone number.

This structure would look similar to:

```
"phoneNumbers": {
  "n1234567890": { // without CC, be warned of overlap
    "userId1": true,
    "userId3": true
  },
  "c011234567890": { // with CC for US
    "userId1": true
  },
  "c611234567890": { // with CC for AU
    "userId3": true
  },
  ...
}
```

#### Notes:

**Why are the phone numbers stored in the format `n###########` and `c###########`?**

This is because Firebase treats numeric keys as indexes of an array. This doesn't make sense for this use case, so we add the `n`/`c` at the start to suppress this behaviour.

**Why use both `n###########` and `c###########`?**

If all entries simply used a `n` prefix, an 11-digit phone number might overlap with a 10-digit phone number that has it's country code added. So we use `n` for normal phone numbers and `c` for numbers that include their country code.

**Why did you say that each key of `/phoneNumbers` contains an *"array"* of user IDs?**

This is because you should avoid using numeric-index arrays in Firebase databases (and arrays in general). Say that two separate processes wanted to update `/phoneNumbers/n1234567890` by removing user IDs. If one wants to remove the ID at position 1 and the other at position 2; they would end up removing the IDs at position 1 and 3 instead. This can be overcome by storing the user ID as the key instead which allows you to add/remove it by ID rather than position.

## Implementation

As you are already using Cloud Functions, implementing such an index is relatively simple. This code can easily be adapted to suit any sort of automatically generated index based on user data.

```
// Initialize functions and admin.
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

/**
 * Listens to operations on the children of `/users` and updates the `/phoneNumbers` index appropriately.
 */
exports.handleNewUser = functions.database.ref('/users/{userId}')
  .onWrite(event => {
    var deltaSnapshot = event.data,
        userId = event.params.userId,
        tasks = []; // for returned promises

    if (!deltaSnapshot.exists()) {
      // This user has been deleted.
      var previousData = deltaSnapshot.previous.val();
      if (previousData.number) {
        tasks.push(removeUserFromPhoneNumber(userId, previousData.number, false));
      }
      if (previousData.numberWithCC) {
        tasks.push(removeUserFromPhoneNumber(userId, previousData.numberWithCC, true));
      }
      // Handle other cleanup tasks.
      return Promise.all(tasks).then(() => {
        console.log('User "' + userId + '" deleted successfully.');
      });
    }

    var currentData = deltaSnapshot.val();

    if (deltaSnapshot.previous.exists()) {
      // This is an update to existing data.
      var previousData = deltaSnapshot.previous.val();

      if (currentData.number != previousData.number) { // Phone number changed.
        tasks.push(removeUserFromPhoneNumber(userId, previousData.number, false));
        tasks.push(addUserToPhoneNumber(userId, currentData.number, false));
      }
      if (currentData.numberWithCC != previousData.numberWithCC) { // Phone number changed.
        tasks.push(removeUserFromPhoneNumber(userId, previousData.numberWithCC, true));
        tasks.push(addUserToPhoneNumber(userId, currentData.numberWithCC, true));
      }
      // Handle other tasks related to update.
      return Promise.all(tasks).then(() => {
        console.log('User "' + userId + '" updated successfully.');
      });
    }

    // If here, this is a new user.
    tasks.push(addUserToPhoneNumber(userId, currentData.number, false));
    tasks.push(addUserToPhoneNumber(userId, currentData.numberWithCC, true));
    // Handle other tasks related to addition of new user.
    return Promise.all(tasks).then(() => {
      console.log('User "' + userId + '" created successfully.');
    });
  );

/* Phone Number Index Helper Functions */

/**
 * Returns an array of user IDs linked to the specified phone number.
 * @param {String} number - the phone number
 * @param {Boolean} withCountryCode - true, if the phone number includes a country code
 * @return {Promise} - a promise returning an array of user IDs, may be empty.
 */
function lookupUsersByPhoneNumber(number, withCountryCode) {
  // Error out before corrupting data.
  if (!number) return Promise.reject(new TypeError('number cannot be falsy.');
  return lookupIdsByIndex('phoneNumbers', (withCountryCode ? 'c' : 'n') + number);
}

/**
 * Adds the user ID under the specified phone number's index.
 * @param {String} userId - the user ID
 * @param {String} number - the phone number
 * @param {Boolean} withCountryCode - true, if the phone number includes a country code
 * @return {Promise} - the promise returned by transaction()
 */
function addUserToPhoneNumber(userId, number, withCountryCode) {
  // Error out before corrupting data.
  if (!number) return Promise.reject(new TypeError('number cannot be falsy.');
  return addIdToIndex(userId, 'phoneNumbers', (withCountryCode ? 'c' : 'n') + number)
}

/**
 * Removes the user ID under the specified phone number's index.
 * @param {String} userId - the user ID
 * @param {String} number - the phone number
 * @param {Boolean} withCountryCode - true, if the phone number includes a country code
 * @return {Promise} - the promise returned by transaction()
 */
function removeUserFromPhoneNumber(userId, number, withCountryCode) {
  // Error out before corrupting data.
  if (!number) return Promise.reject(new TypeError('number cannot be falsy.');
  return removeIdFromIndex(userId, 'phoneNumbers', (withCountryCode ? 'c' : 'n') + number)
}

/* General Firebase Index CRUD APIs */
/* Credit: @samthecodingman */

/**
 * Returns an array of IDs linked to the specified key in the given index.
 * @param {String} indexName - the index name
 * @param {String} keyName - the key name
 * @return {Promise} - the promise returned by transaction()
 */
function lookupIdsByIndex(indexName, keyName) {
  // Error out before corrupting data.
  if (!indexName) return Promise.reject(new TypeError('indexName cannot be falsy.');
  if (!keyName) return Promise.reject(new TypeError('keyName cannot be falsy.');
  return admin.database().ref(indexName).child(keyName).once("value")
  .then(snapshot => {
    if (!snapshot.exists()) return []; // Use empty array for 'no data'
    var idsObject = snapshot.val();
    if (idsObject == null) return [];
    return Object.keys(idsObject); // return array of IDs
  });
}

/**
 * Adds the ID to the index under the named key.
 * @param {String} id - the entry ID
 * @param {String} indexName - the index name
 * @param {String} keyName - the key name
 * @return {Promise} - the promise returned by transaction()
 */
function addIdToIndex(id, indexName, keyName) {
  // Error out before corrupting data.
  if (!id) return Promise.reject(new TypeError('id cannot be falsy.');
  if (!indexName) return Promise.reject(new TypeError('indexName cannot be falsy.');
  if (!keyName) return Promise.reject(new TypeError('keyName cannot be falsy.');
  return admin.database().ref(indexName).child(keyName)
  .transaction(function(idsObject) {
    idsObject = idsObject || {}; // Create data if it doesn't exist.
    if (idsObject.hasOwnProperty(id)) return; // No update needed.
    idsObject[id] = true; // Add ID.
    return idsObject;
  });
}

/**
 * Removes the ID from the index under the named key.
 * @param {String} id - the entry ID
 * @param {String} indexName - the index name
 * @param {String} keyName - the key name
 * @return {Promise} - the promise returned by transaction()
 */
function removeIdFromIndex(id, indexName, keyName) {
  // Error out before corrupting data.
  if (!id) return Promise.reject(new TypeError('id cannot be falsy.');
  if (!indexName) return Promise.reject(new TypeError('indexName cannot be falsy.');
  if (!keyName) return Promise.reject(new TypeError('keyName cannot be falsy.');
  return admin.database().ref(indexName).child(keyName)
  .transaction(function(idsObject) {
    if (idsObject === null) return; // No data to update.
    if (!idsObject.hasOwnProperty(id)) return; // No update needed.
    delete idsObject[id]; // Remove ID.
    if (Object.keys(idsObject).length === 0) return null; // Delete entire entry.
    return idsObject;
  });
}
```

The `handleNewUser` function in the above snippet doesn't catch errors. It will just let Firebase deal with them (by default FB will just log the error). I would recommend implementing appropriate fallbacks as you desire (as you should with any Cloud Function).

Regarding the source code in your question, it would become something similar to:

```
contactsData.forEach((contact) => {
  contact.phoneNumbers.forEach((phoneNumber) => {
    var tasks = [];
    tasks.push(lookupUsersByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber.number, false)); // Lookup without CC
    tasks.push(lookupUsersByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber.number, true)); // Lookup with CC
    Promise.all(tasks).then(taskResults => {
      var i = 0;
      // Elements of taskResults are arrays of strings from the lookup functions.
      // Flatten and dedupe strings arrays
      var userIds = taskResults.reduce((arr, results) => {
        for (i=0;i<results.length;i++) {
          if (results[i] !== null && ~arr.indexOf(results[i])) {
            arr.push(results[i]); // Add if not already added.
          }              
        }
        return arr;
      }, []);

      // Build 'contacts' array (Doesn't need a database lookup!)
      return userIds.map(uid => ({
        name: contact.name,
        phone: phoneNumber.number,
        id: uid
      }));
    }).then(currentContacts => {
      currentContacts.forEach(contact => {
        contactsObj[contact.id] = contact
      });

      // do original code from question here.
      // I'm not 100% on what it does, so I'll leave it to you.
      // It currently uses an array which is a bad implementation (see notes above). Use PUSH to update the contacts rather than deleting and readding them constantly.
    });
  });
});
```

## Note on Security/Privacy

I would highly recommend restricting read and write access of `/phoneNumbers` to just the cloud functions service worker for privacy reasons. This may also require portions of your program logic to be moved to the server depending on permissions problems.

To achieve this, replace:

```
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

with:

```
admin.initializeApp(Object.assign({}, functions.config().firebase, {
  databaseAuthVariableOverride: {
    uid: "cloudfunc-service-worker" // change as desired
  }
});
```

and to enable it, you would need to configure your Firebase Database rules as follows:

```
"rules": {
    "phoneNumbers": {
      ".read": "'cloudfunc-service-worker' === auth.uid",
      ".write": "'cloudfunc-service-worker' === auth.uid"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @samthecodingman for the extended answer. I will go over the answer in more detail to understand it completely and post comments if I have any.