# Cloud function for Firebase error - function crashed out of request scope

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I just saw this error for one of the executions of a cloud function

`Function killed. Error: function crashed out of request scope`

There are no other supporting logs with more information on the Firebase logs console and I couldn't find more information about this error on the web. I have already discussed the funtion for which I received this error in detail in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43223834/cloud-function-for-firebase-timeout-after-60-seconds-while-running-a-bunch-of-fi/43244020). I have a couple of questions

1. What does this error mean? Is there a way to get more information for this error. I tried looking for logs in the Google Cloud console for this function but didn't find anything extra.
2. Is there a way to set alerts when such errors or a `timeout` occurs for an execution of a function?
3. When I look at the details of this function on Google Cloud console, it still says that no errors are reported for this function for the last 7 days. The above error has occurred at least once for this function and this function has also timed out a few times in the last 7 days. Are such events not considered as error events for a function?

Comment: do you found any solution for this issue ?