# Firebase Cloud Functions Change Timeout

Tags: java, android, firebase, networking, google-cloud-functions

I'm using Firebase Cloud Functions library on Android, and using `getHttpsCallable` to call a cloud function.

The problem is that the function needs 10-15 seconds to return the result back to the client, so the client throws an exception `java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout`.

**Code**

```
    // Create the arguments to the callable function.
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("info", info);
    mFunctions.getHttpsCallable(function)
            .call(data)
            .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, String>() {
                @Override
                public String then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) {
                    // This continuation runs on either success or failure, but if the task
                    // has failed then getResult() will throw an Exception which will be
                    // propagated down.
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        String result = (String) task.getResult().getData();
                        Log.v(Constants.LOG_TAG, result);
                        return result;
                    } else {
                        // The condition never was true, always logs the exception.
                        Exception e = task.getException();
                        Log.e(Constants.LOG_TAG, "Failed to join multiplayer room.", e);
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            });
```

How can I change the timeout so the client would wait more before throwing the exception?

**Note.** I'm not using OkHttp, Retrofit or the default system Networking functions, I'm using Firebase Cloud Functions library (`getHttpsCallable`) to call the function.

Comment: possible duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43223834/cloud-function-for-firebase-timeout-after-60-seconds-while-running-a-bunch-of-fi/43244020

Comment: Not really, my cloud function is working perfectly, but it takes long time (which is also good because I want that) but the client (Android app) throws the exception, not the server, so I want to make the client wait more untill the server responds.

Comment: I believe the timeout is 10 seconds and is not configurable with the current Firebase API.  Suggest you [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/).

Comment: I have sent them an "Ask for feature request", but what are the possible work arounds untill they add this feature?

Comment: Maybe you can change your Cloud Function to an HTTPS one and then you have full control on how you call it from your app.

Comment: As a workaround, "push" your command into Realtime Database, use a database trigger to pick that up and process it, then write the result back to another location in the database that the client knows about (with the same push id).

Comment: But this will be expensive since the result is large (a multiplayer room data) and actually it is being written to the database by the function but it returns an optemised version to the client (removing the data that the client doesn't need) so in this case I'll be writing almost the same data to the database twice..

Comment: Im having the same issue. As per @RenaudTarnec suggestion, doing it as a https function will solve your issue. HOWEVER - you lose a lot of simplicity in terms of calling the endpoint and more so security with are available with the 'call' cloud functions, when you do the same via a https you will need to manage your own auth in the functions project.

What we need is the ability to change the time out which seems set to 10 seconds by default, at the very least, it  should be in line with the functions timeout, which is about 60 seconds if I'm not mistaken!

Comment: Just adding my voice, yes, a 60s timeout would ver useful.  I find this 10s rule to be strange given the rest of the 60s timeouts.  A way to change the timeout would be nice.   I am doing a combination of using a callable function, which writes to a specific node, where I can pickup the data.

Comment: We assumed it would match the firebase functions timeout of 60 seconds as well. It would be great to be able to set this in some android config, or even per function when calling it?

Comment: My function returns a Promise that resolves after 1 second, and I'm still getting an exception FirebaseFunctionsException INTERNAL, cat could be the problem?

Comment: @rraallvv I don't think your problem is a timeout problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`firebase-functions` version 16.3.0, [released 15 Mar 2019](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android), adds the ability to [configure the timeout](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/functions/HttpsCallableReference).

Comment: Finally! Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue, so I called https functions with OkHttp instead of getHttpsCallable as a workaround.
The protocol of https.onCall is public.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable

The code of calling https functions with OkHttp is here.
https://github.com/ryuta46/firebase-callable-okhttp/blob/56adc5e29a35bdb3b355c14d734e6145da4b6809/android/app/src/main/java/com/ttechsoft/okhttp_callable/MainActivity.kt#L184-L239

**Editied.**

The code of essential part is below.

```
    private fun callWithOkHttp(functionName: String) {
        val idToken = idToken ?: return
        val instanceId = instanceId ?: return
        val projectId = FirebaseApp.getInstance()?.options?.projectId ?: return
        val url = "https://us-central1-$projectId.cloudfunctions.net/$functionName"


        val jsonData = JSONObject()
        jsonData.put("text", "inputText")


        val json = JSONObject()
        json.put("data", jsonData)

        val requestBody = RequestBody.create(JSON, json.toString())

        val request = Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(requestBody)
            .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer $idToken")
            .addHeader("Firebase-Instance-ID-Token", instanceId)
            .build()


        val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(1 , TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .readTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .writeTimeout(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
            .build()

        Log.i(TAG, "Start Okhttp")
        okHttpClient.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful) {
                    val message = response.body()?.string() ?: "Network Error"
                    runOnUiThread {
                        textOkHttpResult.text = message
                    }

                    return
                }
                runOnUiThread {
                    textOkHttpResult.text = "OK"
                }

                val responseBody = response.body()
                Log.i(TAG, responseBody?.string())
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                val message = e.message ?: "Unknown Network error"
                runOnUiThread {
                    textOkHttpResult.text = message
                }
            }
        })
    }
```