# Firebase Callable Functions socketTimeout on Android

Tags: android, firebase, timeout, google-cloud-functions, cold-start

When calling a Callable Functions that take a long time (for example, after a cold start - 5-10 secs) we're experiencing a SocketTimeOutException on the callable complete listener on Android (we want to call another function once the first function is completed).

1. is it possible to increase the socket timeout on android firebase sdk?
2. how can I decrease/inspect the cold start? (understand which dependency takes a long time)? also, I'm having a cold start after not calling the function around 30 seconds... (which make firebase functions unusable for early-stage startups with small userbase).

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50971356/4815718. I believe the timeout is 10 seconds and is not configurable with the current Firebase API.

Comment: If you would like to be able to change the timeout, file a feature request with Firebase support.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/