# Firebase Functions gives Timeout on Client side after 10s

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am using `getHttpsCallable` to call a cloud function on Android but the function returns with `FirebaseFunctionsException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED` error if it takes more than 10 seconds. When I checked on firebase (Server side), it shows function completed (without any ERROR).

***Note: This function works perfectly on iOS and fails on Android after 10 seconds***

[I tried this solution here as issue appears similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50971356/755621) but still fucntion fails if it takes more than 10s.

I am using latest dependencies in gradle,

```
dependencies {
    // 
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-functions:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:18.0.0'
}
```

Hers is my function,

```
HttpsCallableReference ref = mFunctions.getHttpsCallable("myFirebaseFunction");
ref.setTimeout(600, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
ref.call(Data)
    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<HttpsCallableResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(HttpsCallableResult httpsCallableResult) {
                    Gson jsonData = new Gson();
                    String json = jsonData.toJson(httpsCallableResult.getData());
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
```

Here is the stack-trace log,

> W/System.err: com.google.firebase.functions.FirebaseFunctionsException: DEADLINE_EXCEEDED
>   W/System.err:     at com.google.firebase.functions.FirebaseFunctions$2.onFailure(com.google.firebase:firebase-functions@@17.0.0:258)
>           at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:215)
>           at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
>       Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: timeout
>           at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.newTimeoutException(Http2Stream.java:656)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream$StreamTimeout.exitAndThrowIfTimedOut(Http2Stream.java:664)
>   W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Stream.takeHeaders(Http2Stream.java:153)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http2.Http2Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http2Codec.java:131)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.CallServerInterceptor.intercept(CallServerInterceptor.java:88)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
>           at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:45)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
>   W/System.err:     at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
>           at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
>           at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
>           at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254)
>           at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:200)
>           ... 4 more

**Update: Firebase Console log**

```
 [
 {
   "textPayload": "Function execution took 37358 ms, finished with status code: 200",
   "insertId": "000000-a5fca827-1905-4416-b053-206981a2e5a7",
   "resource": {
     "type": "cloud_function",
     "labels": {
       "function_name": "getBookContentByIdAndDate_v2",
       "project_id": "apotex360",
       "region": "us-central1"
     }
   },
   "timestamp": "2019-07-11T14:23:51.509329740Z",
   "severity": "DEBUG",
   "labels": {
     "execution_id": "5zxmtpmy8gho"
   },
   "logName": "projects/apotex360/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
   "trace": "projects/apotex360/traces/98f9c62f094ff33f4e0524c9231fe126",
   "receiveTimestamp": "2019-07-11T14:23:57.750633081Z"
 },
 {
   "textPayload": "stream finished",
   "insertId": "000000-914deed7-d813-4f86-93d8-7f72d3377e1c",
   "resource": {
     "type": "cloud_function",
     "labels": {
       "project_id": "apotex360",
       "region": "us-central1",
       "function_name": "getBookContentByIdAndDate_v2"
     }
   },
   "timestamp": "2019-07-11T14:23:51.506Z",
   "severity": "INFO",
   "labels": {
     "execution_id": "5zxmtpmy8gho"
   },
   "logName": "projects/apotex360/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
   "trace": "projects/apotex360/traces/98f9c62f094ff33f4e0524c9231fe126",
   "receiveTimestamp": "2019-07-11T14:23:57.750633081Z"
 },
 {
   "textPayload": "Function execution started",
   "insertId": "000000-409caeb7-96cd-4d27-b2b7-ed0546f919be",
   "resource": {
     "type": "cloud_function",
     "labels": {
       "project_id": "apotex360",
       "region": "us-central1",
       "function_name": "getBookContentByIdAndDate_v2"
     }
   },
   "timestamp": "2019-07-11T14:23:14.151990344Z",
   "severity": "DEBUG",
   "labels": {
     "execution_id": "5zxmtpmy8gho"
   },
   "logName": "projects/apotex360/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
   "trace": "projects/apotex360/traces/98f9c62f094ff33f4e0524c9231fe126",
   "receiveTimestamp": "2019-07-11T14:23:20.439670300Z"
 }
]
```

Is there something that I am missing here? I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious that you're doing wrong, looks identical to the solution in the question you linked... only other suggestion might be to try the approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54409683/8026947). Not ideal I'll admit.

Comment: What exactly is the function code on the other side?  And what does your functions logs say in the Firebase console?

Comment: @DougStevenson I updated question with firebase console log. Please have a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug in the Android client library regarding the different types of timeouts available for OKHTTP.  You can read about the fix here:

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/604

Comment: Thank you for the response. It would be helpful if I can know long this release will take.

Comment: I don't control that process. You could comment on that issue to see if there is an estimate.

Comment: Updated version (firebase-functions:18.1.0) with the fix. It is working fine now.