# Verify if a phone number exist in firebase app using firebase cloud function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am new to the firebase (and all its features) space. I have read the documentation, and I have been able to use the web sdk properly. I have created a file where all my current firebase code is written as seen in firebaseApi.js below. Also, below is an example of how I have used the functions under registration.js (Kindly correct if I am doing it wrong), the sample works. I was trying to implement

```
 admin.auth().getUserByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber),
```

which I want to use to check if a currently inputted phone number already exists in the App. But I have read the Admin SDKs cannot be used in client-side environments and should only be used in privileged server environments owned or managed by the developers of a Firebase app. I am kinda lost on how to go around this.
is it possible to connect firebase cloud functions to the client-side like 
I am doing with the firebaseApi?
I have cleaned up the code and kept only the relevant parts

firebaseApi.js

```
        import firebase from 'firebase/app';
        import 'firebase/firestore';
        import 'firebase/auth';
        import 'firebase/database';
        import 'firebase/storage';

        const config = {config};

        firebase.initializeApp(config);

        class Firebase {
          register = ({ fullname, email, phone }) => {
            const user = Firebase.auth.currentUser.uid;
            const firestoreRef = Firebase.firestore.collection('Users').doc(user);

            const settings = {
              fullname,
              email,
              phone,
            };

            firestoreRef
              .set(settings);
          };

          static init() {
            Firebase.auth = firebase.auth();
            Firebase.firestore = firebase.firestore();
            Firebase.database = firebase.database();
            Firebase.storage = firebase.storage();
            Firebase.email = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider;
            Firebase.google = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider;
            Firebase.phoneVerify = new firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider();
            Firebase.phone = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider;
          }
        }

        Firebase.shared = new Firebase();
        export default Firebase;
```

registration.js

```
          import Firebase from './firebaseApi';

          onCompleteReg() {
            const { fullname, email, email } = this.state;

            const settings = {
              fullname,
              email,
              email
            };

            Firebase.shared
              .registerSettings(settings)
              .then(() => {
                console.log('Successful');
              }).catch((e) => {
                console.log(e);
              })
          }
```

Comment: Please limit yourself to a single question per post on Stack Overflow.  Right now, you have several questions, but there seems to be just one primary question.  Please edit the post to narrow the focus down to just the one primary question.  Please feel free to ask other questions separately.

Comment: thanks, I have done that
can you please review the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a matter of privacy and best practices, unless the current user is an administrator, I would not be exposing the ability to check if any given phone number is used by any individual and/or is tied to your application.

#### Wrapped in Cloud Function

As the Admin SDK is to be used only from secure environments, you can only expose it's functionality by way of some API. It is beneficial in this case to handle user authentication and CORS automatically, so I'll use a [Callable Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable). Based on the sensitive nature of such an API, it would also be advised to rate-limit access to it which can be easily achieved using the [`firebase-functions-rate-limiter`](https://github.com/Jblew/firebase-functions-rate-limiter) package. In the below code, we limit the API calls to 2 uses per user and 10 uses across all users, per 15 second period to prevent abuse.

```js
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import { FirebaseFunctionsRateLimiter } from 'firebase-functions-rate-limiter';

admin.initializeApp();

const realtimeDb = admin.database();

const perUserLimiter = FirebaseFunctionsRateLimiter.withRealtimeDbBackend(
    {
        name: 'rate-limit-phone-check',
        maxCalls: 2,
        periodSeconds: 15,
    },
    realtimeDb
);
const globalLimiter = FirebaseFunctionsRateLimiter.withRealtimeDbBackend(
    {
        name: 'rate-limit-phone-check',
        maxCalls: 10,
        periodSeconds: 15,
    },
    realtimeDb
);

exports.phoneNumber = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  // assert required params
  if (!data.phoneNumber) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        'invalid-argument',
        'Value for "phoneNumber" is required.'
      );
  } else if (!context.auth || !context.auth.uid) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        'failed-precondition',
        'The function must be called while authenticated.'
      );
  }

  // rate limiter
  const [userLimitExceeded, globalLimitExceeded] = await Promise.all(
      perUserLimiter.isQuotaExceededOrRecordUsage('u_' + context.auth.uid),
      globalLimiter.isQuotaExceededOrRecordUsage('global'));
  if (userLimitExceeded || globalLimitExceeded) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        'resource-exhausted',
        'Call quota exceeded. Try again later',
      );
  }

  let userRecord = await admin.auth.getUserByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
  return userRecord.uid;
}
```

To call the check, you would use the following code on the client:

```js
let checkPhoneNumber = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('phoneNumber');

checkPhoneNumber({phoneNumber: "61123456789"})
  .then(function (result) {
    let userId = result.data;
    // do something with userId
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error('Failed to check phone number: ', error)
  });
```

#### Attempt by Login

Rather than allow users to find out if a phone number exists or specifically exists on your service, it is best to follow the Phone Number authentication flow and allow them to prove that they own a given phone number. As the user can't verify more than one number en-masse, this is the safest approach.

From the [Firebase Phone Auth Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider), the following code is used to verify a phone number:

```js
// 'recaptcha-container' is the ID of an element in the DOM.
var applicationVerifier = new firebase.auth.RecaptchaVerifier(
    'recaptcha-container');
var provider = new firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider();
provider.verifyPhoneNumber('+16505550101', applicationVerifier)
    .then(function(verificationId) {
      var verificationCode = window.prompt('Please enter the verification ' +
          'code that was sent to your mobile device.');
      return firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId,
          verificationCode);
    })
    .then(function(phoneCredential) {
      return firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(phoneCredential);
    });
```

#### Privileged Phone Search

If you want an appropriately privileged user (whether they have an administrator or management role) to be able to query users by a phone number, you can use the following scaffolding. In these code samples, I limit access to those who have the `isAdmin` claim on their authentication token.

Database structure: (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44968616/3068190) for more info)

```js
"phoneNumbers": {
  "c011234567890": { // with CC for US
    "userId1": true
  },
  "c611234567890": { // with CC for AU
    "userId3": true
  },
  ...
}
```

Database rules:

```js
{
  "rules": {
    ...,
    "phoneNumbers": {
      "$phoneNumber": {
        "$userId": {
          ".write": "auth.uid === $userId && (!newData.exists() || root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('phoneNumber').val() == ($phoneNumber).replace('c', ''))" // only this user can edit their own record and only if it is their phone number or they are deleting this record
        }
      },
      ".read": "auth != null && auth.token.isAdmin == true", // admins may read/write everything under /phoneNumbers
      ".write": "auth != null && auth.token.isAdmin == true"
    }
  }
}
```

Helper functions:

```js
function doesPhoneNumberExist(phoneNumber) {
  return firebase.database.ref("phoneNumbers").child("c" + phoneNumber).once('value')
    .then((snapshot) => snapshot.exists());
}
// usage: let exists = await doesPhoneNumberExist("611234567890")

function getUsersByPhoneNumber(phoneNumber) {
  return firebase.database.ref("phoneNumbers").child("c" + phoneNumber).once('value')
    .then((snapshot) => snapshot.exists() ? Object.keys(snapshot.val()) : []);
}
// usage: let usersArray = await getUsersByPhoneNumber("611234567890") - normally only one user

function searchPhoneNumbersThatStartWith(str) {
  if (!str || str.length < 5) return Promise.reject(new Error('Search string is too short'));
  return firebase.database.ref("phoneNumbers").startAt("c" + str).endAt("c" + str + "\uf8ff").once('value')
    .then((snapshot) => {
      let phoneNumbers = [];
      snapshot.forEach((phoneEntrySnapshot) => phoneNumbers.push(phoneEntrySnapshot.key));
      return phoneNumbers;
    });
}
// usage: let matches = await searchPhoneNumbersThatStartWith("61455")

// best handled by Cloud Function not client
function linkPhoneNumberWithUser(phoneNumber, userId) {
  return firebase.database.ref("phoneNumbers").child("c" + phoneNumber).child(userId).set(true);
}
// usage: linkPhoneNumberWithUser("611234567890", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)

// best handled by Cloud Function not client
function unlinkPhoneNumberWithUser(phoneNumber, userId) {
  return firebase.database.ref("phoneNumbers").child("c" + phoneNumber).child(userId).remove();
}
// usage: unlinkPhoneNumberWithUser("611234567890", firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
```

Comment: thanks @samthecodingman.... I know how to go about it this way
I would like to know if there is any chance that can be done in the cloud function using admin sdk?

Comment: @vincentO I've added an appropriate Cloud Function for consideration

Comment: Many thanks man, I am quite new to the react native, firebase and nodejs environment, what’s the best way to call that api function you’ve written in the client-side.